# WinApi CreateDialog returns error 715

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to get this simple windows dialog to spawn but as soon as I start it it reports "Error x715" which means `hDialog` was not correctly made in the `int WINAPI WinMain()` function. It compiles just fine.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and it's a "Visual C++ -> `Empty Project`" project.

This is the full `main.cpp` file, which is the only file in the project:

```
#include "windows.h"

#define DLG_MAIN 200 // ID for dialog
#define DLG_ICON 30000 // IDs for icons
#define DLG_ICON_S 30000
#define IDC_QUIT 1011 // ID for "quit"-button
#define IDC_INFO 2000 // ID for "info"-button
#define ID_TIMER 1 // ID for timer
#define IDC_STATIC -1 // ID for all labels
#define TIMER_INTERRUPT 500 // timer msg interval in msec 

HINSTANCE TheInstance = 0; // instance handle of this program

// Our main function
void lalala(HWND hwnd)
{
    /*Doesn't do anything yet.*/
}

// Windows passes messages to application windows to indicate "something"
// needs to be done
BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // set the time to generate a timer message (WM_TIMER)
        SetTimer(hwnd, ID_TIMER, TIMER_INTERRUPT, NULL);
        return TRUE;

        case WM_TIMER:
        // a timer msg was received so call our main function!
        lalala(hwnd);
        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
        {
            case IDC_INFO:
            // the info button on the window was pressed
            MessageBox(hwnd, "<show some info>", "The Jonas Brothers are way better than Nick Cave ever was.", MB_OK);
            return TRUE;

            case IDC_QUIT:
            // the quit button on the window was pressed
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        // this app is about to be closed so kill the timer
        KillTimer(hwnd, ID_TIMER);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return TRUE;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        // destroy the window
        DestroyWindow (hwnd);
        return TRUE;
    }
return FALSE;
} 

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, char * cmdParam, int cmdShow)
{
    TheInstance = hInst;
    HWND hDialog = 0;

    hDialog = CreateDialog (hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE (DLG_MAIN), 0, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
    if (!hDialog)
    {
        char buf [100];
        wsprintf (buf, "Error x%x", GetLastError ());
        MessageBox (0, buf, "CreateDialog", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }

    HICON hIcon = LoadIcon (TheInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (DLG_ICON));
    SendMessage (hDialog, WM_SETICON, WPARAM (TRUE), LPARAM (hIcon));
    hIcon = LoadIcon (TheInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (DLG_ICON_S));
    SendMessage (hDialog, WM_SETICON, WPARAM (FALSE), LPARAM (hIcon));

    MSG msg;
    int status;
    while ((status = GetMessage (&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (status == -1) return -1;

        if (!IsDialogMessage (hDialog, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage ( &msg );
            DispatchMessage ( &msg );
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it fails at `hDialog = CreateDialog (hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE (DLG_MAIN), 0, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);` ?

Comment: You *really* need to get rid of the (DLGPROC) cast, it hides a bug in your code.  The error says that you didn't write your resource script properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 0x715 is ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND, which you get when it fails to find the dialog with the name that you supplied, in the resource section. Instead of  declaring the macros for each resources, just use `#include "resource.h"`

Comment: You're off by one, it is resource *type* not found.

Comment: `cannot open source file resource.h` when I try to `#include "resource.h"`. It's not obvious to me what resource.h even is. Where does it reside?

Comment: @nat; Are you using the resource editor in Visual Studio? If so, this should all happen relatively seamlessly. Yes, it automatically creates and maintains a file named `resource.h` containing the symbols of all your app's resources.